# Singular/plural forms of abbreviations of expressions with "of" in the middle

Tags: abbreviations

Is it grammatically correct to abbreviate expressions with *of* in the middle? If so, what will be the singular and plural forms of such abbreviations if the word that changes is not the last one in the expression?

In particular, I am interested in *quantity of interest*. My guess is *QoI* for singular and *QoIs* for plural.

And here is yet another question: should *o* for *of* be capitalized as well?

Comment: Think MPs *Members of Parliament*.

Comment: Abbreviations are **adopted** after careful consideration of many factors, including other existing ones. You cannot make up your own one if there already exists a standard abbreviation for the expression or if the abbreviation already has a standard expansion. http://www.abbreviations.com/QOI http://www.acronymfinder.com/QOI.html

Comment: Dictionaries and other reference works do not "adopt" abbreviations or set standards for them. When they decide to document an abbreviation, they base their decision on the frequency with which the abbreviation is found "in the wild", not on its suitability or uniqueness or any other prescriptive factor. There is also absolutely nothing wrong with making up your own abbreviation as long as you explain it so the reader understands what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to abbreviate *Quantity of Interest* to either *QoI* or *QOI*. Their plural forms would be *QoIs* and *QOIs* respectively.

Capitalising the *O* is a matter of style. Since *QoIs* looks a little odd, it might be better to capitalise the abbreviation to *QOI* which would make its plural *QOIs*. If you're working with a style guide, it will be a good idea to consult it to see if it has anything to say on the matter.